# Change the content of "Highlighted Content" webpart in Sharepoint via buttons?

Tags: sharepoint, office365

I want to use buttons on my Sharepoint page to change the content of the "Highlighted Content". This could be "Most Recent", "Expired", "Approved". When a button is clicked, I want the query that "Highlighted Content" to change. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a way to do this. The best approach I found was using Powerapps (connected to the Sharepoint site) and then embedding it into a Sharepoint page. You can achieve something similar that way.